# where is the directory bb101repo-pratice

Tags: macos, git

I am following the Atlassian tutorial for configuring my local system and Gitbucket to work together. On `Step 7` The instruction reads `"[Go] to a terminal on your local system and navigate to your bb101repo-pratice repo. Then, do the following for Git and Mercurial:"`

What is the path to the `bb101repo-pratice repo`? I didn't skip any steps so I know I haven't missed any instructions on how to created such a directory. I did a search on `This Mac` and nothing showed up.

Comment: What if you look for `bb101repo-practice` (with **two** `c`s, and without the `repo` at the end, which isn't part of the path).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder So do you mean: `bb101-practice`? Do you mind spelling it out for me?

Comment: @ learner: I **did** spell it out for you: `bb101repo-practice`. You were saying `bb101repo-pratice repo`, missing out the first `c` and adding `repo` to the end as though it were part of the path. It isn't, it's part of the sentence, like "go to the `blah` directory". "Directory" isn't part of that path, just part of the sentence. Other than this, we can't tell you where you put the directory. It's your computer. In general, you should find it as a subdirectory of wherever you ran the pull/clone command.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Ha! Thanks. I did `find / -name "bb101repo-practice"` but got no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repo is originally called "**`bb101repo`**", and it is described in the "[Create an Account and a Git Repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Create+an+Account+and+a+Git+Repo)" help page.

> Click `Repositories > Create repository` or the `Create a repo` button on the page.
>   The system displays the `Create new repository` page.
>   Take some time to review the dialog's contents. With the exception of the Repository type, everything you enter on this page you can later change.
>
> Enter bb101repo for the Name field.

The [clone help page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+Your+Git+Repo+and+Add+Source+Files) or the [SSH setup page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) show its GUI:

[image: bb101repo]

You will find it referenced with other names like **`bb101practice`** (in the [branching page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Branching+a+Repository)).

The idea is for you to take the repo you initially created during the 101 steps (using whatever name you gave it at that time)